# Can I replace the whole Redux Store in a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can I replace a whole Redux store in a reducer?  I can successfully change other parts to it, like editPage, position and playlistList and its contents.. but I can't seem to get this to work.  Is this not allowed?  or am I doing this wrong?

My InitialState (initialState.js)

```
export default {
  playlist: {
    editPage: {},
    playlistList: [],
    position: 0
  }
};
```

Action

```
export function setStorePlaylist(store) {
  return { type: types.SET_STORE_PLAYLIST, store: store };
}
```

Reducer

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import update from 'immutability-helper';

export default function storeReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case types.SET_STORE_PLAYLIST: {
      // i tried both of these with no luck
      return update(state, {playlist: {$set: action.store}});
      return Object.assign({}, state, {playlist: action.store});
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can definitely replace the whole state in a reducer (your terminology of replacing the "Redux store" is not quite right). The code you have posted looks fine on the surface.  Can you describe HOW it's not working? State not updating? Error in console?  Are you using the [redux dev tools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to get some visibility on what's going on?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper it just looks like nothing is happening.  I put a breakpoint in the reducer and it returns everything.. but when i console.log my redux store or look at it in the Redux plugin.. nothing changed at all.. so i dont understand unfortunately... hm.

Comment: Can't say I understand either.  It looks fine to me, so without being able to run your code and debug it myself, I'm not sure if I can be any more help to you (happy to take a look at a repo if you are able to share it).

Comment: i think what you mean is replacing reducers, replacing store would mean you will need to run the createStore again